# R - checking for NAs in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame such as

```
ID   a     b     c
29   NA    2     NA
11   3     1     1
9    NA    NA    NA
```

I'd like to pull out the rows that have at least 1 value filled in for all the columns except for the `ID`. For example, the row with `ID=9` would not satisfy that condition, because all the columns after the `ID` column are `NA`.

You might think one way would be

```
d = d[!is.na(d$a) | !is.na(d$b) | !is.na(d$c),]
```

however in my case, there are like 20 columns after the `ID` column, not just three.

What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[ , -1])) > 0, ]

#   ID  a b  c
# 1 29 NA 2 NA
# 2 11  3 1  1
```